# With an accurate model of an ancient site, how can I import an accurate night sky star map (ex. 3300 BC, 12 midnight) to relate to its features?

Tags: rendering, import

I have an accurate Blender model of an ancient site that has features likely oriented to specific star patterns ( maybe sunrise as well ) around 3300 BC. I'm trying to import a night sky into Blender that can help test alignment of the model with the star patterns and be used to produce a video explaining the orientations. Ideally a rendering applied to the inside of a sphere, so the camera can be placed anywhere within the model to examine star alignments. The star map application would have to be accurate, can backdate and can paint the 3D interior accurately enough that angles to various stars from a fixed point in the model would be correct.

If Blender isn't the right tool for this, suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Are you asking about how to put any star map into a Blender scene so to have it as the sky background, or are you asking how to get accurate star maps for specific dates?

Comment: It would be a combination of an accurate star map for a specific date, imported into a Blender scene so that a model of an ancient architecture can be aligned to it to show alignments of physical structures to the stars around 3300 BC.

Comment: What I'm asking is: are you looking for a star map or do you have no idea how to put it in the background of a Blender scene? Because only the latter is a suitable question for this site. Looking for star maps is offtopic since it has nothing to do with how to use Blender.